# Issues with EPiServer Profile properties in web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, web-config, episerver

I'm trying to add a Profile Property inside my web.config, which I want to be a List containing PageData.

**EDIT :** this is how it looks in web.config where the properties are declared:

```
<profile defaultProvider="DefaultProfileProvider">
  <properties>
    <add name="Address" type="System.String" />
    <add name="ZipCode" type="System.String" />
    <add name="Locality" type="System.String" />
    <add name="Email" type="System.String" />
    <add name="FirstName" type="System.String" />
    <add name="LastName" type="System.String" />
    <add name="Language" type="System.String" />
    <add name="Country" type="System.String" />
    <add name="Company" type="System.String" />
    <add name="Title" type="System.String" />
    <add name="CustomExplorerTreePanel" type="System.String" />
    <add name="FileManagerFavourites" type="System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]" />
    <add name="EditTreeSettings" type="EPiServer.Personalization.GuiSettings, EPiServer" />
    <add name="ClientToolsActivationKey" type="System.String" />
    <add name="FrameworkName" type="System.String" />
    <add name="ShortcutData" type="System.Collections.Generic.List`1[EPiServer.Core.PageData]" />
  </properties>
  <providers>
    <add name="DefaultProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultProfileProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="EPiServerDB" applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</profile>
```

As you can see I can have a List here without any problems, but I cannot use the PageData I want because it cannot be found.

This gets an error that says EPiServer.Core.PageData cannot be found, I'm not sure how this works in the web.config, but I tried adding it like this as well:

```
<add name="ShortcutData" type="System.Collections.Generic.List`1[EPiServer.Core.PageData]", EPiServer />
```

Where I thought "EPiServer" was the namespace/assembly/something that it would search through, but it couldn't find EPiServer and changed it automatically to something like this (not exactly though):

```
<add name="ShortcutData" type="System.Collections.Generic.List`1[EPiServer.Core.PageData]", mscorlib, name="System.Collections.Generic" publicKeyToken="407dd0808d44fbdc" culture="neutral" />
```

I don't even know if what I'm trying to achieve is possible, but if you know how to fix it, or do something similar I would greatly appreciate it! :)
Also, I would really like to know what exactly the following "EpiServer" field does, is it the assembly as I thought?

Regards
deSex

Comment: Why do you want to store the PageData object? Why not just store the ContentLink ID?

Comment: Because I would like to get several properties from the PageData object, without having to get multiple properties.
I guess I might be able to do what I want if I make two properties which represents the ID and the Name of the pageLink, instead of PageData.
I would rather have PageData if possible though.

Comment: Storing the whole PageData object will be a big overhead and my guess it that the profile serialization would have trouble recreating a PageData object correctly as well. If you want multiple properties from the PageData object, why not create a custom class with exactly those properties?